# Insert form data into sqlite3 query without php in TideSDK

Tags: php, sqlite, tidesdk

I have been searching for hours and it is probably just me being a novice but I am having a very hard time figuring out how to dynamically enter text into a sqlite3 query as they do not accept variables (or so I believe).

Here is what I am attempting to do:

A user can currently view recipes in my TideSDK app - the content of the recipe is generated from a file called recipes.db

This code loads an individual recipe into the main screen:

```
function doMainChange70() {
    var db = Ti.Database.openFile(Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.getApplicationDataDirectory(), 'recipes.db'));
    var rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE number = '70'");
    while (rows.isValidRow()) {
    $('#foodFoto').empty();
    $('#titleArea').empty();
    $('#servings').empty();
    $('#tagline').empty();
    $('#ingredients').empty();
    $('#directions').empty();
    $('#nutrition').empty();
    $('#foodFoto').append("<img src='foodPics/r" + rows.fieldByName('number') + ".jpg' />");
    $('#titleArea').append("<p>" + rows.fieldByName('title') + '</p>');
    $('#servings').append("<p>" + rows.fieldByName('servings') + '</p>');
    $('#tagline').append("<p>" + rows.fieldByName('tagline') + '</p>');
    //$('#ingredients').
    $('#directions').append("<p>" + rows.fieldByName('directions') + '</p>');
    $('#nutrition').append("<p>" + rows.fieldByName('nutrition') + '</p>');
    $('#editBtn').remove();
    $('#mainBtns').append("<a href='#' id='editBtn'" + 'onclick=' + 'editRecipe' + rows.fieldByName('number') + "()><img src='RecipeButton5.png' /></a>");
    rows.next();
    rows.close();
    db.close();
    return false;
}
```

}

I would now like the user to be able to edit the recipe. Currently when the edit button is clicked all of the fields of the recipe change to input tags and the user can edit:

```
function editRecipe70() {
$('#editBtn').removeAttr('onclick');
var db = Ti.Database.openFile(Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.getApplicationDataDirectory(), 'recipes.db'));
var rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE number = '70'");
while (rows.isValidRow()) {
$('#editBtn').html("<img src='saveRecipeButton.png' />");
$('#formContainer').empty();
$('#formContainer').append("<form id='sendEdit'><textarea type='text' name='title' id='title'>" + rows.fieldByName('title') + "</textarea><br>" + "<textarea type='text' name='servings'>" + rows.fieldByName('servings') + "</textarea><br>" + "<textarea type='text' name='tagline'>" + rows.fieldByName('tagline') + "</textarea><br>" + "<textarea type='text' name='directions'>" + rows.fieldByName('directions') + "</textarea><br>" + "<textarea type='text' name='nutrition'>" + rows.fieldByName('nutrition') + "</textarea><br>" + "<input type='submit'></form>");
```

}

My problem is that at this point I can't figure out a way to capture what the user has placed in the input fields (or more accurately textareas) and place it into the sqlite3 query string.

I am able to query the db in js with something like this:

```
UPDATE recipeTable SET title='best recipe ever' WHERE number='70';
```

But nothing like this (which is what I need):

```
UPDATE recipeTable SET title = '[formValueForTitle]' WHERE number = '70';
```

Hopefully I am making sense, I do apologize it is my first question. I have looked at many posts here on the site and the immediate solution would seem to be preprocessing the form values using php but I have read the php module in TideSDK doesn't have sqlite3 support right now and I have been unable to bring the processed code back into the index.html to run in js.

So long and short, I would like to figure out a way to let users edit recipes and I am totally stuck. Any direction would be much appreciated!

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it:

```
 var inputfromform = 'I got this back from the form';
  var number = 7;
  db = Ti.Database.open(dbname); // or openFile etc
  db.execute("BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION;");
  db.execute("UPDATE recipeTable SET title = ? WHERE number = ?;", inputfromform, number);
  db.execute("COMMIT TRANSACTION;");
  db.close();
```

Hope this helps